# Extern declaration of variable with no link to a definition

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int i;

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

From what I understand, there is no global variable named `i` to which the external declaration of `i` should refer. So it should produce a linker error. Yet this code runs successfully and prints `5`. Why so?

Comment: Do you know what is variable's scope?

Comment: The global variable `i` is not being referenced, because you are giving it a more local definition. The program will always use the 'most local definition with the specified name'.

Comment: Change `int i = 5` to `i = 5` and you'll get the error you expect.

Comment: The requirement in the standard is that if the global `i` *is used in an expression* there shall be a definition.  Since you never use it, there is no requirement for a definition .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int i;   // this is one variable called "i"

int main()
{
    int i = 5;  // it is second variable called "i"
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

You have variable `i` declared (but never defined) in the global (file) scope.
You also have variable `i` defined in the local scope of function `main`. The global scope `i` and the automatic function scope `i` variables are not related.

As you never use the global `i` it was optimized out by the compiler and the linker did not have to search for the object `i` in object and library files.

BTW your `main` function should be `int main(void)` not  `int main()`